# Remove Item From Set with Matching Criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I have two sets of tuples where each tuple is `(x, y, flag)`.  I would like to combine them together such that the combination function will remove and replace any *x, y* value in set *A* that is in set *B* regardless of the flag.  For example:

```
A = {(1,1.5,1),(1,2.5,0),(2,2.5,1)}
B = {(1,1,1),(1,2.5,1),(2,2.5,0)}

f(A,B)
>>> 
{(1,1,1),(1,1.5,1),(1,2.5,1),(2,2.5,0)}
```

Does anyone know a quick and elegant way to do this? If you have a better way to do this with different data structures, let me know.

Comment: You have to iterate and check manually then

Comment: I think doable with set comprehension as in suggested answer below, but I don't understand the remove/replace rule as stated below.  How did (1, 1, 1) get into the result if (1, 1, ?) was not in A to start?

Comment: Because it is a union of the two sets such that B items replace A items if they exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = {(1,1.5,1),(1,2.5,0),(2,2.5,1)}
B = {(1,1,1),(1,2.5,1),(2,2.5,0)}

print(set({(a, b): (a, b, c) for s in [A, B] for (a, b, c) in s}.values()))
```

Prints:

```
{(1, 2.5, 1), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2.5, 0), (1, 1.5, 1)}
```